# java generics in scala sometimes fail with cast exception

Tags: scala, generics, elasticsearch, classcastexception

So this is a pretty specific problem, but might be related to issues other may have experience, though I could not find a good solution.

in our specific case, we are using [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch). the problematic piece of code is this:

```scala
val hit: org.elasticsearch.search.SearchHit = {...}

val innerSystemField: Option[Long] =
  Try(hit.field("system.innerField").getValue) match {
    case Success(x) => Some(x.asInstanceOf[Long])
    case Failure(e) => {
      logger.error("exception during innerField retrieval", e)
      None
    }
  }
```

so, it doesn't really matters we are using Elasticsearch, what matter, is the library API. so, here's the [`SearchHit` interface's `field` method](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/search/SearchHit.java#L148) which returns an instance of `SearchHitField`. and here's the [`SearchHitField` interface's `getValue` method](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/search/SearchHitField.java#L51). the method is declared as:

```java
<V> V getValue();
```

and this is where the problem lies. the mapping which we defined Elasticsearch with, guarantee that the returned value will always be a `Long`. but every once in a while we get a `Failure` containing a `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to scala.runtime.Nothing$`. The thing is, that if I explicitly write the type, it won't compile:

```
[error] /home/me/projects/my-project/src/main/scala/com/org/project/MyElasticsearchCode.scala:123: polymorphic expression cannot be instantiated to expected type;
[error]  found   : [V]()V
[error]  required: Long
[error]           Try[Long](hit.field("system.innerField").getValue) match {
[error]                                                   ^
[error] one error found
[error] (project/compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 4 s, completed Jul 27, 2015 4:16:41 PM
```

So how do I get around this problem?

Comment: Can you provide a stacktrace of the ClassCastException?

Comment: it won't help. the exception is thrown from the line of the `Try`'s apply. all the rest of the stack trace is all my caller code...

Comment: Can you do `getValue[Long]` ?

Comment: @PeterNeyens - apparantly I can! didn't thought it would compile, so I haven't eve tried it. but it compiles with `Try[Long]`, which will hopefully stop throwing sporadic exceptions every once in a while...

Answer (score 0):

I find the message of the `ClassCastException` a bit confusing. Maybe you could try this:

```
val innerSystemField: Option[Long] =
  Try[Any](hit.field("system.innerField").getValue) match {
    case Success(x: java.lang.Long) => Some(x.asInstanceOf[Long])
    case Failure(e) => {
      logger.error("exception during innerField retrieval", e)
      None
    }
  }
```

Comment: I can, but how is it any different from not writing the type at all?

Comment: If you don't give `Try` or `getValue` (as Peter Neyens suggested) a type argument, scala tries to infer the type, which in this case seems to fail.

Comment: But the problem is in runtime. not compile time. most of the times it works. but every once in a while, the cast exception is raised...  since it's not a problem I can easily check since it rarely happens, I'll try @PeterNeyens solution first, because it feels more concise, and let it run for a few days. if it won't work, I'll try your solution as well. thanks anyway!

Comment: Hmm, I may be completely off, but just out of curiosity, is it running on a HotSpot VM?

Comment: $ java -version 
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)

Comment: I am not an expert on any of this, but HotSpot uses *adaptive optimization* which again encompasses *dynamic recompilation*. So, I wonder what this would do to our precious scala code, as the HotSpot VM probably does not entertain a scala compiler.